# How to display a character instead of ascii?

Tags: json, go, escaping

This is my testing code. Just make a simple HTTP server. Then generating a JSON data that it values is "&". But the result is what I don't want. The result is below the code block.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func testFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := make(map[string]string)
    data["key"] = "&"
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "generator json error")
    } else {
        //print console
        fmt.Println(string(bytes))
        fmt.Println("&")
        //print broswer
        fmt.Fprintln(w, string(bytes))
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "&")
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", testFunc)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe", err)
    }

}
```

result:
Chrome browser show:

```
{"key":"\u0026"}
&
```

Console also show:

```
{"key":"\u0026"}
&
```

When `&` not in JSON, browser and console will print `&`.

Comment: Ok.I edited just now.This is complete code.

Comment: What is wrong with the output?

Comment: What's wrong with that? `var o = {"key":"\u0026"}; o.key === '&'` returns true.

Comment: I see some documentation, and search Google.As you see, output is not wrong, but how can i see '&' when it's as value in json ? Everytime browser show is \u0026

Comment: The string is valid json. See the RFC at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt Section 2.5. Strings

Comment: That's the normal encoding of JSON format. Just deal with it or don't use JSON. Any JSON parser will translate it correctly, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Thx a lot.Of course, judged by javascript is good method.But is there some method showing '&' directly just with golang. As you see, when using 'fmt.Fprintln(w, "&")', browser prints '&',not '\0026'.

Comment: Why don't you just use native go functions to print this structure ? Before marshalling it, just do `fmt.Println("%v", data)`. And client side, you have to parse the JSON string before outputting it : `console.log(JSON.parse(string))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop json.Marshal from escaping < and >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595664/how-to-stop-json-marshal-from-escaping-and)

Answer (score 27):

In Go1.7 they [have added](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ab52ad894f453a02153fb2bc106d08c47ba643b6) a new option to fix this:

> encoding/json:
>   add Encoder.DisableHTMLEscaping This provides a way to disable the escaping of <, >, and & in JSON strings.

The relevant function is

```
func (*Encoder) SetEscapeHTML
```

That should be applied to a *Encoder*.

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
```

The example of stupidbodo modified: https://play.golang.org/p/HnWGJAjqPA

Answer (score 17):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Search struct {
    Query string `json:"query"`
}

func main() {
    data := &Search{Query: "http://google.com/?q=stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8"}
    responseJSON, _ := JSONMarshal(data, true)
    fmt.Println(string(responseJSON))

}

func JSONMarshal(v interface{}, safeEncoding bool) ([]byte, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(v)

    if safeEncoding {
        b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("\\u003c"), []byte("<"), -1)
        b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("\\u003e"), []byte(">"), -1)
        b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("\\u0026"), []byte("&"), -1)
    }
    return b, err
}
```

Results:

```
JSONMarshal(data, true)
{"query":"http://google.com/?q=stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8"}

JSONMarshal(data, false)
{"query":"http://google.com/?q=stackoverflow\u0026ie=UTF-8"}
```

Credits: https://github.com/clbanning/mxj/blob/master/json.go#L20

Playbook: http://play.golang.org/p/c7M32gICl8

Comment: what would be the case if you wanted to support more utf-8 characters?  do you have to replace each character manually?  I dont think this should be done manually.. there has to be another way

Comment: `SetEscapeHTML` from Go 1.7 should probably be used instead of manually replacing characters.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) (emphasis by me):

> String values encode as JSON strings. InvalidUTF8Error will be returned if an invalid UTF-8 sequence is encountered. The angle brackets "<" and ">" are escaped to "\u003c" and "\u003e" to keep some browsers from misinterpreting JSON output as HTML. **Ampersand "&" is also escaped to "\u0026" for the same reason.**

Apparently if you want to send '&' as is, you'll need to either create a custom Marshaler, or use RawMessage type like this: http://play.golang.org/p/HKP0eLogQX.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve the problem is to simply replace those escaped characters in [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) into just valid UTF-8 characters, after the [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) call.

You can use the [`strconv.Quote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote) and [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to do so.

```
func _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(_jsonRaw json.RawMessage) (json.RawMessage, error) {
    str, err := strconv.Unquote(strings.Replace(strconv.Quote(string(_jsonRaw)), `\\u`, `\u`, -1))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func main() {
    // Both are valid JSON.
    var jsonRawEscaped json.RawMessage   // json raw with escaped unicode chars
    var jsonRawUnescaped json.RawMessage // json raw with unescaped unicode chars

    // '\u263a' == '☺'
    jsonRawEscaped = []byte(`{"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}`) // "\\u263a"
    jsonRawUnescaped, _ = _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(jsonRawEscaped)                        // "☺"

    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawEscaped))   // {"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}
    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawUnescaped)) // {"HelloWorld": "안녕, 세상(世上). ☺"}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pUsrzrrcDG-

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any other solution?