# golang json marshal converts tags to utf symbols

Tags: go

How to prevent converting `<p>`  to `\u003cp\u003e` in `json.Marshal` ?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    user := User{Name: "<p>Frank</p>"}
    b, err := json.Marshal(&user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(user)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

It outputs:

```
{<p>Frank</p>}
{"Name":"\u003cp\u003eFrank\u003c/p\u003e"}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fcg_N1kYLp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [golang - display character, not ascii. Like '&', not '\0026'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656624/golang-display-character-not-ascii-like-not-0026)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656624/golang-display-character-not-ascii-like-not-0026). In short - you can create your own Marshaller implementation if you need to preserve these characters, but even encoded the json output will be a perfectly valid one and should not break anything.