# Getting 403 "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access" when trying to upload to GCS with signed URLs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to upload files directly from the browser to GCS using [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). I'm generating a `v4` signed URL from an App Engine Standard PHP application and that seems to be working fine. The problem is when I try to `PUT` to that URL I get a `403` with the following XML response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access denied.</Message>
  <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to <bucket-name>/some-object.txt.</Details>
</Error>
```

My app engine service account has `Service Account Token Creator`, which enabled the URL to be created.

I've enabled CORS on the bucket to accept `PUT` to `*`, which allowed me to get to where I am now.

I've switched from `v2` URLs to `v4` as an issue on the Go SDK suggested that was a problem.

I'm generating the signed URL using the PHP Google Cloud Library like so:

```php
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('<bucket-name>');
$object = $bucket->object('some-object.txt');

$url = $object->signedUploadUrl(new \DateTime('tomorrow'), ['version' => 'v4']);
```

I've tried adding the service account to the bucket's permissions and adding `Storage Object Admin`, `Storage Object Creator`, etc. but nothing seems to get me past this `403` (apart from opening it up to `allUsers`).

In [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/uploading-images-directly-to-cloud-storage-by-using-signed-url) article is says

> In addition, within Cloud Storage, you need to grant the following permissions to generate a Signed URL.
>
> - `storage.buckets.get`
> - `storage.objects.create`
> - `storage.objects.delete`

But I just can't work out which role they need to be added to.

At this point, I think there is one of two possibilities:

1. The signed URL is not actually working because it should be authenticated as the service account and not anonymous. In this case, what could be causing this?
2. Signed URLs authenticate as some type of anonymous role but that role does not have the permissions. In which case, how do I add the permissions for that role (`allUsers` is obviously wrong)?

---

**SOLVED:**

There was a number of things wrong with my implementation:

1. As suggested by Brandon & Charles below, `signedUploadUrl` is not appropriate for a direct `PUT`. To get around this, I needed to use `beginSignedUploadSession`
2. As suggested by John below, I needed to have `Storage Object Creator` added on the service account user. This however, is already added on a GAE default service account as it is `Project Editor`
3. `Service Account Token Creator` needs to be explicitly added to the service account as `Project Editor` doesn't seem to cover it.
4. I was embedding the URL into Javascript with Twig uses `const url='{{ upload_url }}';`, however Twig automatically HTML encodes variables so that was breaking the URL, instead, I needed to use `{{ upload_url|raw }}`. This broken format was the reason that the message included `Anonymous caller`

Comment: A few questions/suggestions: What does the generated URL look like? Are you using a POST to initiate a resumable upload using that URL, or are you attempting to directly upload data to the provided URL? If the latter, you may want to use `beginSignedUploadSession` instead.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I'm doing `PUT` directly to the URL and I've tried both `signedUploadUrl` and `beginSignedUploadSession`, in both cases the error is the same.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough the URL is too long to post here so I've put it on [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/M7khzsWx)

Comment: There error means that the Identity that you used to create a Signed URL does not have `storage.objects.create`  Add a Cloud Storage role to the service account used to create the Signed URL.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've added `Storage Object Creator` to both the app engine service account and the permissions on the bucket with the service account, sadly I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: As a test, in your code where you create the storage client, specify the service account JSON file manually. If this works, then you know that you are adding permissions to the wrong account. Without seeing the actual account and JSON policy I can only point you in a direction to figure this out.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ok, I seem to be getting closer, I just asked the StorageClient to output the service account it was using and it's different, however, I can find the one listed anywhere in my IAM settings. The name is `service-799272800318@gs-project-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, any idea where i might find the `gs-projects-accounts` service account?

Comment: Not all service accounts will appear in IAM. You can add them manually (by the email address) and then assign roles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197432/discussion-between-tomphp-and-john-hanley).

Comment: When the number of comments becomes large, it is time to rewrite the question so that the comments are not required.

Comment: I have (rather embarrassingly) got it working. The problem was that the template rendering engine (Twig) was HTML encoding the URL (as can be seen in the pastbin link above) where it wasn't needed (in JavaScript). Even so, this has not been a waste of time as the suggestions here have really helped me understand how signed URLs & service accounts work better. Thank you for taking the time to help me! (I will rewrite the question in the morning to reflect everything better.

Comment: The 4th trick solved the problem in my case. Thank you. In writing a function in Go, I called `json.MarshalIndent()` to convert an object to JSON but this function implicitly escapes ampersands `&`. ref: [*How to stop json.Marshal from escaping < and >?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595664/how-to-stop-json-marshal-from-escaping-and)

Answer (score 1):

`signedUploadUrl` creates a URL for the POST HTTP method (see the library source code at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/StorageObject.php). You are using that signed URL for a PUT request, so the request isn't permitted. The error message does not show this as the problem, but I think that's what it really is.

You can either look into how to upload a file via POST, or create a signed URL for PUT. I've done the latter in Python, but I don't see a way to do it with this library. I'm not a PHP programmer so I might be missing it.

Or you could create your own code to create a signed URL for PUT, starting with the library code as an example. Signed URLs are extremely tricky to get exactly right, and creating your own code will probably be frustrating. It was for me in Python.

Comment: I've now move to `beginSignedUploadSession()` which is supposed to allow direct `PUT` requests and it's giving the same error.

Comment: @tomphp I know it's been a while but how did you solve it?

Comment: I had the exact same issue, it was because the signed url was not encoded properly.