# unicode character in result execute template

Tags: go

I have this template

```
<data><datos name={{.Name}} phone={{.Phone}} email={{.Email}}></data>
```

And I'm running it like this:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
t := template.Must(template.New("dataPdf").Parse("<data><datos name={{.Name}} phone={{.Phone}} email={{.email}}></data>"))
err := t.Execute(buf, data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
return buf.String()
```

All values ​​are overridden, but for some reason the `<` and `>` characters remain in `unicode`

```
\u003cdatos\u003e\
```

I update:

Verify and the error doesn't occur until this string value is assigned to a specific Struct object and then I try to convert it to json.

Comment: `.email` needs to be capitalized...

Comment: @StevenPenny I fixed it but the problem persists.

Comment: `data` is also undefined. You also have a `return` statement but no `func`. Can you please post an example that we can run without having to change anything?

Comment: sorry, update my question, my error.

Comment: The encoding/json package escapes "<", ">", "&" so the resulting JSON is safe to embed in HTML (see documentation [here](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal)).   The escaped characters are valid JSON and decode as expected. Use  [SetEscapeHTML](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder.SetEscapeHTML) to disable escaping.

Comment: The question is about JSON encoding, not about templates.  See answer to actual question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595664/how-to-stop-json-marshal-from-escaping-and/28596225).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop json.Marshal from escaping < and >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595664/how-to-stop-json-marshal-from-escaping-and)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this. See a working example on the Go Playground https://play.golang.org/p/xKmjgzZxeES.

The output of the code below is

```
<data><datos name=Joe phone=123-456-7890 email=hunter2@a.com></data>
```

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

type Person struct {
    Name  string
    Phone string
    Email string
}

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    t := template.Must(template.New("dataPdf").Parse("<data><datos name={{.Name}} phone={{.Phone}} email={{.Email}}></data>"))

    data := Person{Name: "Joe", Phone: "123-456-7890", Email: "hunter2@a.com"}

    err := t.Execute(buf, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(buf.String())
}
```