# Decode Marshalled JSON unicode

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

I think the quickest way to explain my problem is with an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/UbtCdVv-kv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type JSON struct {
    Body string
}

func main() {
    body := "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"

    obj := JSON{body}

    result, _ := json.Marshal(obj)
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}
```

Output:

> {"Body":"\u003chtml\u003e\u003cbody\u003eHello World\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e"}

I'd like the result to be a utf8-encoded string that reads the same as it went in. How can I achieve this? I tried to use `utf8.DecodeRune,` in a loop:

```
str := ""

for _, res := range result {
    decoded, _ := utf8.DecodeRune(res)
    str += string(decoded)
}
```

but that causes a [compilation error](https://play.golang.org/p/1ErAJ4geF0)

> main.go:21: cannot use res (type byte) as type []byte in argument to utf8.DecodeRune

And calling `DecodeRune` on the marshalled object returns the [first character](https://play.golang.org/p/Z_aSPTLu6A), as you'd expect

> {

Edit: I'm  using Go 1.6.2, which apparently doesn't have `SetEscapeHTML` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intended behavior. From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> String values encode as JSON strings coerced to valid UTF-8, replacing
>   invalid bytes with the Unicode replacement rune. The angle brackets
>   "<" and ">" are escaped to "\u003c" and "\u003e" to keep some browsers
>   from misinterpreting JSON output as HTML. Ampersand "&" is also
>   escaped to "\u0026" for the same reason. This escaping can be disabled
>   using an Encoder that had SetEscapeHTML(false) called on it.

You can get the required result by using an `Encoder` and calling `SetEscapeHTML(false)` on it:

```
func main() {
    body := "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"

    obj := JSON{body}

    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
    enc.Encode(obj)
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/lMNCJ16dIo

Comment: I see it works on the playground, but when I copy it into my own environment I'm getting a compilation error: `enc.SetEscapeHTML undefined (type *json.Encoder has no field or method SetEscapeHTML)`. I'm using Go 1.6.2 if that changes anything

Comment: Could be that the method is unavailable in `1.6.2`. Try checking your version's docs as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487704/go-packages-documentation-for-a-previous-version

Comment: Hmm, yep. The docs have no mention of `SetEscapeHTML` and don't offer any other alternatives.

Comment: SetEscapeHTML was added in Go 1.7.

Comment: Since json library does this to only three characters, you can try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656624/golang-display-character-not-ascii-like-not-0026

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to achieve this is to simply replace those escaped characters into unescaped UTF-8 characters. (I used to do this to make non-English letters to be human readable in JSON.)

You can use the [`strconv.Quote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Quote) and [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unquote) to do the conversion.

```
func _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(_jsonRaw json.RawMessage) (json.RawMessage, error) {
    str, err := strconv.Unquote(strings.Replace(strconv.Quote(string(_jsonRaw)), `\\u`, `\u`, -1))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func main() {
    // Both are valid JSON.
    var jsonRawEscaped json.RawMessage   // json raw with escaped unicode chars
    var jsonRawUnescaped json.RawMessage // json raw with unescaped unicode chars

    // '\u263a' == '☺'
    jsonRawEscaped = []byte(`{"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}`) // "\\u263a"
    jsonRawUnescaped, _ = _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(jsonRawEscaped)                        // "☺"

    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawEscaped))   // {"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}
    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawUnescaped)) // {"HelloWorld": "안녕, 세상(世上). ☺"}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pUsrzrrcDG-

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, here's the reason for the compiler error.

json.Marshal returns a byte slice (`[]byte`), not a string.

When you iterate over a byte slice using `range`, you are not iterating over its *runes* but over single bytes at a time.  You can't use `DecodeRune()` on a byte value - it expects a rune, which is a 32-bit integer value representing a Unicode code point.  This is what you'd get if you iterate using `range` on a *string*.

Now, from what you are wanting to achieve, it doesn't look like you want DecodeRune at all.

The other answer adequately describes how to tell the JSON encode not to escape `<` and `>` characters ie

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
```